# how to upload pdf file along with SOAP API as multipart/form-data post in rails 4 + savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, ruby-on-rails-4, multipart, savon

> Requirement: Response of "transaction_id" from the API and while uploading parameters,we also required to pass a pdf file along with this API,but there is no parameter to send file with the API.So we are doing like this in our model as multipart/form-data to http request.

http://xyz.xyz.com/xyz/upload.ashx?u=username&p=passwordtid=ticketGuid

User name     "xxxxxxx" 
Password      "yyyyyy" 
tid           "f155a1e5-d1cd-4edb-8d25-89f3852a06f4"

Response required is TransID(decimal)

Our model code is below,

require "net/http"

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_update :upload_ticket_file

```
has_attached_file :ad_pdf
validates_attachment_content_type :ad_pdf, :content_type => "application/pdf"
validates_attachment :ad_pdf, :presence => true

validates :section_id, :section, :colour_id, :colour, :size_id, :sizes, :height, :width, :height_bleed, :width_bleed, :booking_number, :presence => true

def generate_xml_ticket
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:ads='http://adstream.com/' xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><env:Body><ads:AddTicketToPool><ads:XMLTicket><![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><jobbag><jobentry><colour_name /><page_setup><bleed_depth>#{(self.height_bleed.to_f*2.83).round(2)}</bleed_depth><bleed_width>#{(self.width_bleed.to_f*2.83).round(2)}</bleed_width><trim_depth>#{(self.height.to_f*2.83).round(2)}</trim_depth><trim_width>#{(self.width.to_f*2.83).round(2)}</trim_width></page_setup><named_size>#{self.sizes.split('/').last}</named_size><number_of_columns>#{self.size_number_of_columns}</number_of_columns><publication_code>#{self.publication_code}</publication_code><publisher_code>#{PUBLISHER[:code]}</publisher_code><section_code>#{self.section.split('/')[1]}</section_code><style>3</style><attention/><instructions /><booking_number pscode='BkNo' psformat='pZ1F' pstitle='Booking #' pstype='1'>#{self.booking_number}</booking_number><publication_date pscode='RnDt' psformat='yZ00' pstitle='Publicaiton Date' pstype='1'>#{self.issue_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")}</publication_date><caption /><insertion_number/><production_key /><customer_name pscode='ACNm' psformat='sZ00' pstitle='Ad Client Name' pstype='1'>#{PUBLISHER[:company_name].to_s}</customer_name><any pscode='APro' psformat='NZ00' pstitle='Brand' pstype='1'>#{self.brand}</any><any pscode='Camp' psformat='nZ00' pstitle='Campaign' pstype='1'>#{self.campaign}</any><any pscode='Rpla' psformat='bP00' pstitle='Replacement Material' pstype='1'>false</any><any pscode='Hard' psformat='BP00' pstitle='Hard Proof Sent' pstype='1'>false</any></jobentry><job_common><operator>#{self.attention_to}</operator><file_name>#{self.ad_pdf_file_name}</file_name></job_common></jobbag>]]></ads:XMLTicket></ads:AddTicketToPool></env:Body></env:Envelope>"
end

def upload_ticket_file
    # response = system("curl -v -F media=@#{self.ad_pdf.path} -F message='#{self.ad_pdf_file_name}' '#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_UPLOAD_URL}?u=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_USERNAME}&p=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_PASSWORD}&tid=#{self.ticket_guid}'"
    # uri = URI.parse(ADSTREAM_QPWEB_UPLOAD_URL+"?u=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_USERNAME_ENCODED}&p=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_PASSWORD}&tid=#{self.ticket_guid}")
    boundary = "ABASDASDSAKJDFKDFNDKFDKFJDKNDFDN"
    uri = URI.parse(ADSTREAM_QPWEB_UPLOAD_URL+"?u=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_USERNAME_ENCODED}&p=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_PASSWORD}&tid=#{self.ticket_guid}")
    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    puts ADSTREAM_QPWEB_UPLOAD_URL+"?u=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_USERNAME_ENCODED}&p=#{ADSTREAM_QPWEB_PASSWORD}&tid=#{self.ticket_guid}"
    file = self.ad_pdf.path
    post_body = []
    post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='datafile'; filename='#{self.ad_pdf_file_name}'"
    post_body << "Content-Type: application/pdf"
    post_body << File.read(file)+boundary
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.body = post_body.join
    request["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data"
    request.add_field('session', boundary)
    response = http.request(request)
    puts request.inspect
    puts response.inspect
    if response and (response.body != "ticketnotaddedtostore" and !response.body.to_s.blank? and response.body != "incorrectquerystrings")
        if self.update_attribute(:transaction_id, response.body)        
            client = Savon.client(namespace_identifier: :ads) do
                wsdl ADSTREAM_QPWEB_URL
                log true
            end
            message = {TransID: self.transaction_id}
            response = client.call(:check_status) do 
                message (message)
            end
            self.update_attribute(:check_status_result, response.body.to_hash[:check_status_response][:check_status_result])
        end
    end
end
```

end

class JobXMLTicket

```
def to_s
    builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
    builder.instruct!(:xml, encoding: "UTF-8")

    builder.jobbag { |jo|
        jo.jobentry { |je|
            je.colour_name
            je.page_setup {|ps|
                ps.bleed_depth "0.0"
                ps.bleed_width "0.0"
                ps.trim_depth "725.66"
                ps.trim_width "1150.86"
            }
        }
    }
    builder
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Using 'RestClient gem' we can do the needful

```
require "net/http"

require 'savon'

require 'rest_client'

$config = {
  qpweb_upload_url: 'http://example.com/WebAPI/upload.ashx'
}


class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   def uploadPdf
    q = URI.encode_www_form( {
        :u => USERNAME,
        :p => PASSWORD,
        :tid => ticket_guid
      })
    response = RestClient.post( $config[:qpweb_upload_url] + '?' + q, :file  =>File.open(self.ad_pdf.path, 'rb') ) 
    id = /transid=(.*)/.match( response.to_str )
    raise 'error uploading file' if !id
    puts 'TransactionId: ', id[1]
    return id[1]
  end
end
```